# bootstrap switch without text-label

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to use bootstrap switch without having the white space (`data-text-label`) between both `data-on-label` and `data-off-label` options. And I could probably sort this out but I must move on to other stuff due to dead-lines for the project i'm working on.

[image: what i want to remove]

I would apreciate a lot if anyone knows how to achive this and shares it whith me.

Answer (score 1):

I am pulling the answer out of your question and putting it here to help future visitors.

This can be accomplished with a few changes to the switch CSS

`label` `width:0` the main child `div` `width:200%` and the options `span`s with `width:50%`.

Comment: This answer should probably be wikified.

Comment: How exactly do you mean this? Make the changes in the bootstrap-switch.css?